# Unable to retrieve variable assigned in function

Tags: python, function, user-input

I am writing a function where it gets input from the user and sets the  variable `answer` to the answer the user gives. I am printing `answer` outside of the function, but for some reason, it doesn't print anything.

```py
answer = " "   # set empty in the start
def ask(question):
    answer = input(question) # sets the answer to the user's input
ask("how are you ")
print(answer)  # ends up printing nothing.
```

Comment: the variables that are declared inside a function are called local variables. the values assigned to the variables inside the function will stay in the function only. In order to get the desired output add a print or return statement in the function return answer or print(answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must print answer:

1. inside of ask function,
   or
2. return answer, catch it and then print it

---

```
answer = " "   # set empty in the start
def ask(question):
    answer = input(question)
    return answer
    
answer = ask("how are you ")
print(answer)
```

---

or one line:

```
print(ask("how are you "))
```

Answer (score 0):

`answer` inside `ask()` creates a fresh variable called `answer`; it does *not* refer to the variable declared above `ask()`.

The cleanest way to resolve this is to return the user's input from `ask()` and then directly assign it to `answer`. (You could also use the `global` keyword, but that's generally considered bad practice.)

```py
def ask(question):
    return input(question)
answer = ask("how are you ")
print(answer)
```

Comment: Is there any possible way for me to refer to a variable inside of a function without having to set the "answer" variable to the asking function outside of the function?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `global` keyword. Use your original code, but insert `global answer` as the first line of the `ask()` function body. That being said, this can make your code pretty hard to read, so use this sparingly.